# WPF MessageBox is not displayed at all if long message is passed

Tags: wpf, messagebox

I ran into situation when some MessageBoxes with error messages were not displayed at all. After closer investigation, I was able to narrow down the problem to cases when a very long string is passed as `messageBoxText`.

In such cases, call `MessageBox.Show` does not display anything, returns `MessageBoxResult.No` and, in most cases, there's a message in the `Output` window saying `The thread 0xHEXNUMBER has exited with code 0 (0x0)`. For me, this method silently fails.

This is very strange - WPF is a very mature technology and I expect this code to work [according to spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.5#System_Windows_MessageBox_Show_System_String_) or throw some exception (e.g. OutOfMemory, StackOverflowException). I've debugged the program and no manged or unmanged exceptions are thrown and caught.

What is the root cause of MessageBox not being displayed? Is there some easy way to debug such things (since no exceptions are thrown or logged). What is the messageBoxText length limit and what does it depend on (I could check that empirically on my computer, but would be conclusive for one OS/platform/.NET Framework version at best)?

**Repro:**

Here's a code  which demonstrates the problem (it can be used with standard WPF Application template in Visual Studio).

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="LongMessageInMessageBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="ShortMessage_Clicked">Short Message</Button>
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Click="LongMessage_Clicked">Long Message</Button>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace LongMessageInMessageBox
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// Method which shows that displaying short message works correctly
        private void ShortMessage_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ShortMessage_Clicked");
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Short Message");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        /// Method which shows that displaying a long message does not work
        private void LongMessage_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LongMessage_Clicked");
            var longTextBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(10000);
            longTextBuilder.Append("Long Message \n");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
            {
                longTextBuilder.Append(" ").Append(i);
            }
            var result = MessageBox.Show(longTextBuilder.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        } 
    }
}
```

Sample from `Output` window:

```
ShortMessage_Clicked
OK
ShortMessage_Clicked
OK
LongMessage_Clicked
No
The thread 0x55bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: My guess is that it fails silently as WPF does often. Did  you check?

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox` class in `WPF` (and WinForms) wraps the Win32 `MessageBox` function, and doesn't throw an exception. In the old Win32 world error is reported by setting the last-error code, and if you don’t call `GetLastError` to check, you can just keep going without knowing something is broken.

From [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/MessageBox.cs,451867ccabfb0df5)

```
//so it just translates the return code to a MessageBoxResult

MessageBoxResult result = Win32ToMessageBoxResult (UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox (new HandleRef (null, owner), messageBoxText, caption, style));
```

I have not tested the capacity of the `lpText` string in the [Win32 MessageBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox). But it is not surprising if the capacity limit is something like `1024`, `4096` or `65536`, after all, `MessageBox` function is designed to display short message.